# Apex Regex to remove the special character

Tags: apex

I need the RegEX to remove all special characters and spaces
(667) 788-9900, I want to be 6677889900

And it should work for (667) 788, then I should get 667788.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
replaceAll('\\D','');
```

This will remove anything that is not a digit from the phone number.

Credits - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008yP9IAI

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = '(667) 788';
String newStr = str.replaceAll('\\D', '');
System.debug('Final : '+newStr);
```

Done !!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/67935)

Comment: @Martine - This works fine. I have already implemented this in my project.

Comment: You're just answering the same solution than @NikhilKhivansara.

Comment: To be fair, their answer was posted in the same minute. Also, this one compiles, not so sure about the other one.